# Spring vs Angular js - Rest URLs getting exposed

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, frontend

I have a backend REST app. I'm presently developing the frontend app. Now i have a confusion as to how to setup the frontend app.

Case 1 - Plan to use Spring and have a frontend controller layer that takes care of calling the REST services. But i need to have models and POJOs setup same as in the backend to parse the JSON response. This seems like a overload on frontend. How to go around about this?

Case 2 - Plan to use Angular.js. Then i need to have all my REST URLs in the controller.js which is completely accessible for anyone. That way im totally exposing my REST domain, URL and request format. Is it not a security threat? How to go around about this?

Can you please tell me which case is better and secure and how to resolve the problem attached with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secure your REST endpoints using a scheme like OpenId or OAuth or something else. Spring and numerous other web app frameworks have components to help with such authentication.

AngularJS is a client side framework. You can use Angular along with Spring. They are not mutually exclusive.

Finally, any http request (including RESTful http requests) invoked on a client is easily accessed simply by viewing the network traffic. Chrome, Firefox, along with other browsers provide tools, out of the box, that make this very easy to do. All the more reason to secure those REST endpoints.

Comment: If i use AngularJS fraamework, i can make REST calls from Angular in either services.js or factory.js. If i use Spring i can have controller layer to make REST calls. And have them render on JSP pages. So is there any specific advantage to use Angular along with Spring? Or can i use either Angular or Spring standalone? I'm a lot confused about this, kindly clear it.

Comment: in some respect, it comes down to preference. angular provides a nice client side framework for building complex js driven web ui's. It is quite robust. An Angular app may also coexist with jsps, but it is not necessary. Given the technologies you've selected, it may make sense to use Spring to implement the back end REST services and Angular to invoke them from the client